# Access Repeater controls propeties

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to to use `Response.Redirect()` to redirect to a page with a query string value, because i can't set this value.
I have a repeater that contains `ImageButton` and a `Label`, the label's text is retrieved from DB, i need to response to a page with URL`"ShowCourse.aspx?coursename=value"` where value is the value of the label.

Code of repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CoursesListRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="FetchCourse">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="CourseImage" runat="server" Height="90" Width="90" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("CourseImage")%>' CssClass="imageButtons" OnClick="CourseImage_Click" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="CourseNameLabel"><a href='<%#String.Format("AboutCourse.aspx?coursename={0}",Eval("CourseName")) %>' style="font-family: 'Buxton Sketch'; font-size: 40px;"><%#Eval("CourseName") %></a></asp:Label>
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Label ID="CategoryLabel" runat="server" Font-Size="22px" ForeColor="Gray" Text='<%#Eval("CourseCategory") %>' />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" Font-Size="13px" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CourseDescription") %>' ForeColor="DarkRed" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <hr style="margin-top: 30px; border-radius: 5px;" />
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CommandName & CommandArgument on the ImageButton like this:

Template:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CoursesListRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="FetchCourse" 
            onitemcommand="CoursesListRepeater_ItemCommand"></asp:Repeater>
    ....
    <asp:ImageButton ID="CourseImage" runat="server" Height="90" Width="90" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("CourseImage")%>' CssClass="imageButtons" 
        CommandName="ShowCourse" CommandArgument='AboutCourse.aspx?coursename=<%# Eval("CourseName") %>' />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void CoursesListRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ShowCourse")
        {
            Response.Redirect(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, but i am asking about to Redirect to another page after clicking the ImageButton with a query string value which is equal to the label beside the image

Comment: Great, it's working, but the url in the browser is the same as in the html code:
"http://localhost:4302/AboutCourse.aspx?coursename=%3C%# Eval("CourseName") %>"

Answer (score 0):

Better to add a property named `Url` to your class and use the above method and set the `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Url")%>'`
Keep in mind that you have to create the redirect url from our code behind and set it to Repeater's data items's `Url` property you newly added